# Watch event for specific object

Tags: azure, go, kubernetes, kubebuilder

We have an k8s operator (based on kubebuilder) which works as expected, now we need support for listening to secrets on the cluster.

The following code is working however I got event for **all the secrets** in the cluster which is **not efficient**,

I WANT to get the event **only for specific secret**, lets say secret with specific `labels/annotation`, how we can do it?

```
func (r *InvReconciler) SetupWithManager(mgr ctrl.Manager) error {
    manager := ctrl.NewControllerManagedBy(mgr).
        For(&corev1alpha1.Inv{}, builder.WithPredicates(predicate.Or(predicate.GenerationChangedPredicate{}, predicate.AnnotationChangedPredicate{}))).
        WithOptions(controller.Options{
        })

    manager = manager.Watches(&source.Kind{Type: &v1.Secret{}}, handler.EnqueueRequestsFromMapFunc(func(a client.Object) []reconcile.Request {
        return r.secretHandler.GetSecret(a.GetNamespace(), a.GetName())
    }))

    return manager.Complete(r)
}
```

this is the function

```
func (secretReq secretHandler) GetSecret(namespace string, name string) []reconcile.Request {

    fmt.Println("secret is: ", namespace, "--", name)
    return nil
}
```

lets say secret like the following and only for this secret (with labels `foo: bar` )i'll get the event when it was created or modified

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  labels:
    foo: bar
  name: mysecret
  namespace: dev
type: Opaque
data:
  USER_NAME: YWRtaW4=
  PASSWORD: dGVzdBo=
```

Im **not** talking about an `if statement` after I got the event as it already bring all the secrets event in the cluster.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible. See my answer for the details.

Comment: I don't have the answer for your issue, however, I know an open source controller that does what you want to achieve, and it's written in GO as well. Here it is https://github.com/mittwald/kubernetes-replicator, hope it helps!

Comment: @Fares, this does not include watching for CRUD changes as the OP wants to achieve. It only allows for replication / syncing of k8s resources.

Comment: Oh, I must be misunderstanding the need then, sorry about that 

Comment: @Fares, no problem. I checked out the code in repo you posted and did not find any CRUD watcher. Now lets hope that I get some votes for my answer  more often than not people who post bounties do not respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, in a roundabout way. You need to configure the selector into the controller Manager that you use to set up your reconciler.

You can use label or field selectors for this.
You can either set the same selector for all types of objects using `DefaultSelector`, or you can use `SelectorsByObject` to have different selectors for different types of objects.

```
import (
    corev1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/labels"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/selection"
    "k8s.io/client-go/rest"
    ctrl "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime"
    "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/cache"
    "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/manager"
)

func startReconciler(cnf *rest.Config) error {
    mgr, err := ctrl.NewManager(cnf, manager.Options{
        NewCache: func(conf *rest.Config, opts cache.Options) (cache.Cache, error) {
            // Use this selector for everything that is not mentioned in SelectorsByObject
            opts.DefaultSelector = cache.ObjectSelector{
                Label: labels.SelectorFromSet(labels.Set{"foo": "bar"}),
            }
            // Specific selectors per type of object
            opts.SelectorsByObject[&corev1.Secret{}] = cache.ObjectSelector{
                Label: labels.SelectorFromSet(labels.Set{"foo": "bar"}),
            }
            return cache.New(conf, opts)
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    r := &InvReconciler{}
    if err := r.SetupWithManager(mgr); err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

Comment: I don’t see any watcher in here, are you sure this watches for CRUD changes?

Comment: You need to call SetupWithManager with the manager created by this code, as the OP has already posted the the question. No charges needed from what the OP posted

Comment: HI, thanks. so this code should be used in the main as I see it, am I right? is there a way to use it inside the controller (I mean the code inside `SetupWithManager`), if yes could you please provide an example? and how should I connect this `NewCache` function to `secret` object and not all the objects which contain `for:bar` labels?

Comment: another question, when I get the event in the function how should I know which type of event it , create/update/delete ...

Comment: @PJEM you an use SelectorsByObject to have a different selector per type of object. I have updated the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works, I've provided the bounty. one last question how should I know that type of event is , In case I got update and especially `delete` for the secret?

Comment: You just need to check - try to get the secrets that you expect to exist, and if they don't, then they got deleted

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt - yes, but what about update ...any idea how to identify it in a clean way? as I dont want to read and than compere etc

Comment: If you look at the [docs for the controller-runtime package](https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime#example-package), it has an example implementation of a reconciler. Reading and comparing seems to be the right approach.

Comment: HI, can you please check the following to see if you can help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74677080/controller-reconcile-on-object-changes

Answer (score 3):

According to this [github](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/issues/694) source, you should be able to select specific objects (e.g. secrets) with `EnqueueRequestForObject`. However, it is **not** possible (yet) to watch only for specific secret CRUD changes.

> **EnqueueRequestForObject** to watch for your CRD resource changes. In
> your CRD reconciler, you'd fetch all of the TLS secrets using a label
> selector based on the search definition and then run your merge logic
> with the matched secrets.
>
> **EnqueueRequestFromMapFunc** to watch for
> secret changes and trigger a reconcile of one or more CRs. In your
> mapper function, you'd fetch all of the CRs. For each CR that has a
> search definition that matches the passed in secret, you'd create a
> new reconcile.Request for the CR, and return the list of requests,
> which would trigger your CRD reconciler for each CR that matched.

The cleanest way is using a label selector and then merge the results with your existing code. An example of using a label selector is given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56356932/7950592):

```
func GetSecret(version string) (retVal interface{}, err error){
  clientset := GetClientOutOfCluster()
  labelSelector := metav1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels: map[string]string{"version":version}}

  listOptions := metav1.ListOptions{
    LabelSelector: labels.Set(labelSelector.MatchLabels).String(),
    Limit:         100,
  }
  secretList, err := clientset.CoreV1().Secrets("namespace").List(listOptions)
  retVal = secretList.Items[0]
  return retVal, err
}
```

Comment: HI, sorry for the delay in my response, currently not feeling best :), thanks. not sure that I got how it make the "watch" better/ cleaner , as each changes in any secret on the cluster (also in you example) will invoke the `GetSecret` method, so how it can more `cleanset` ? as you write above...what am I missing here? could you provide example to illustrate it please ?